# Creating an element outside it's bounding box using absolute positioning and overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-position

I have created a speech bubble as an absolutely positioned element which I hope to make sit outside of it's wrapper.

I've managed to position the div in the correct place, however the content outside of the div is being clipped.

I used `overflow:visible` to try and make it show but it doesn't seem to be correct?

**CSS**

```
#bubble{
width:201px;
height:189px;
position:absolute;
left:-87px; 
bottom:0; 
z-index: 99;
overflow:visible;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <!-- Speech bubble-->
<div id="bubble"><img src="images/hire_me_bubble.png" 
                 alt="Hire me" />
</div>
```

[Live site](http://www.jamesperrett.co.uk/testsite) - bubble in question can be seen in lower contact section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of the clipping seems to be one of the `div`s containg it: `#contactwrapper`. It has `overflow` set to `hidden`. Setting it to `visible`, causes it to become fully visible, but moves it due to the readjusting of its parent container.

Once it's visible, you can either just reposition it `absolute`ly (which I don't recommend), or try adjusting the parents size, and floating.

I hope this helps! :)